# nginx and REMOTE_HOST

Tags: php, apache, nginx, plesk

I have a VPS with Plesk that has a nginx+apache setup.

The problem: REMOTE_HOST php $_SERVER environment value contains the domain name of the website, instead of the client's host name.

I've enabled "HostnameLookups On" in apache2.conf (= httpd.conf).

However, because nginx is in between the client and Apache, it seems it's not properly setting REMOTE_HOST. If I connect directly to the php page through the Apache port, the REMOTE_HOST variable is set correctly!

Does anyone have a clue? Been trying to figure it out for hours and nothing seems to work.

I need it to work, because eventually I want to deny from host names in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

you should rather consider to use Fail2Ban, when you have Plesk installed on your server, because you seem to miss the fact, that your ".htaccess" - file will be completely ignored by nginx.

Pls. consider as well to include MORE informations about your current Plesk version and the operating system on your server, if you desire more help and keep in mind, that the **Plesk Community forum** offers quite a lot of suggestions and work - arounds for Plesk and it's components and as well for the possible extensions: **=>** https://talk.plesk.com